# How to make animated NSCursor?

Tags: macos, animated-gif, nscursor

Is there a way to make animated `NSCursor` with my custom gif image?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no--your best bet is to create an array of `NSCursor`s, one for each frame of your image, and set them yourself using whatever animation strategy you'd like (perhaps an `NSTimer`?).